# Mapbox unclustered circle change to icon

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can i change this to be an icon instead of this circle with color? I have tried using "layout" & "options" instead of "paint". I also looked in here but didn't find anything which could fit with this. I'm still new to Mapbox/Leaflet.

```
                 map.addLayer({
                 id: 'unclustered-point',
                 type: 'circle',
                 source: 'people',
                 filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
                 paint: {
                 'circle-color': '#21ba45',
                 'circle-radius': 11,
                 'circle-stroke-width': 3,
                 'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
                 }
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an icon in Mapbox, you need to load your image first (png, webp, or jpg format):

```js
map.loadImage(
  './marker-icon.png', // Path to your image here
  (error, image) => {
  if (error) throw error;
     map.addImage('icon_name', image);
});
```

Then you have to change your layer type from `circle` to `symbol`.

The `fill` applies to a form but not to an image, so you'll have to use `layout` instead. Here is an example:

```js
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'layer_id',
  'type': 'symbol',
  'source': {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': data
  },
  'layout': {
    'icon-image': 'icon_name', // The name has to match with the image loaded
    'icon-size': 0.85,
    "icon-allow-overlap": false // This can be 'true' if you want to display all the markers 
    },
});
```